# How can I improve this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, mysql

I am relatively new at working with jQuery. I have the following code written that works with a form that populates three boxes for a year, make, and model for a vehicle. The year is coded in php to already be listed when the user clicks the year box. The make and model are called from a mysql database to populate the list for them to choose from.

But as of now the query for the make and model have a bit of a lag before they will populate the list. Is there anything here that can be done to improve the code? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
$(function(){
$('#year').change(function getmakes(){
    var vehyear = $("#year").val();
    $("#model").html('<option value="">-- All Models --</option>');
    $.ajax({
           url: "/widgets/makes.php",
           global: false,
           type: "POST",
           async: false,
           dataType: "html",
           data: "year="+vehyear, //the name of the $_POST variable and its value
           success: function (response) //'response' is the output provided
                       {
                    //counts the number of dynamically generated options
                    var dynamic_options = $("*").index( $('.dynamic')[0] );
                    //removes previously dynamically generated options if they exists (not equal to 0)
                    if (dynamic_options != (-1)) $(".dynamic").remove();
                    $("#make").html(response);
                    $(".first").attr({selected: ' selected'});

                   }
          });
          return false
});
$('#make').change(function getmodels(){
    var vehyear = $("#year").val();
    var vehmake = $("#make").val();
    $.ajax({
           url: "/widgets/models.php",
           global: false,
           type: "POST",
           async: false,
           dataType: "html",
           data: "year="+ vehyear+"&make="+vehmake, //the name of the $_POST variable and its value
           success: function (response) //'response' is the output provided
                       {
                     //counts the number of dynamically generated options
                    var dynamic_options = $("*").index( $('.dynamic')[0] );
                    //removes previously dynamically generated options if they exists (not equal to 0)
                    if (dynamic_options != (-1)) $(".dynamic").remove();
                    $("#model").html(response);
                    $(".first").attr({selected: ' selected'});                        
                   }
          });
          return false
});
```

});

Comment: I'd consider removing the `async: false` so you don't lock up the browser. Aside from that, any delay would likely be on the server, not here, so you can look into caching the data in memory on the server instead of calling the DB every time, or if the full dataset is small enough, dump the whole thing on the page into a javascript object, then you can pull from there instead of hitting the server each time.

Comment: I think that it would have to be called from the server each time. Every time the user changes the year it has to repopulate the make based on what make of car was produced that year.

Comment: You're probably right for this set - if it was smaller, it might be worth the tradeoff of sending the entire set to the page every time, but every year, make, and model of cars would probably be kind of big, even gzipped. But it's definitely going to be small enough that you should be able to cache it in memory on the web server. That would at least clear up some database traffic and skip one hop per web request.

Comment: Unfortunately as it turns out my hosting provider doesn't allow caching in mysql.